# Move character to end of word?

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla JavaScript how can I accomplish moving specific characters to the end of a word/string? The special chacracters being '!' , '?' , '.'

For example, I have: ags.bay

Which needs to be: agsbay.

Here is my full code:

```
var consonantArray = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
"p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "z"];
var vowelArray = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"];
var enteredText = 'never forget to empty your vacuum bags. please';
var wordArray = enteredText.split(' ');
var finalText = [];

for (i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
//if the first letter of the array is a vowel then change
if (consonantArray.indexOf(wordArray[i].charAt(0)) == -1) {
    finalText[i] = wordArray[i] + "yay";
} else if (vowelArray.indexOf(wordArray[i].charAt(0)) == -1) {
    if (vowelArray.indexOf(wordArray[i].charAt(1)) == -1) {
        finalText[i] = wordArray[i].substring(2) + wordArray[i].charAt(0) + wordArray[i].charAt(1) + "ay"
    } else {
        finalText[i] = wordArray[i].substring(1) + wordArray[i].charAt(0) + "ay";
    }
}
}
console.log(finalText.join(' '));
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt yet? Please show your code and research

Comment: I hit enter too soon on my post and it posted before I had the chance to add. I added my code. I have been messing around with regex and substring, but never fully got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to get all the special character `!`, `?` and `.` in an array using `string#match`. Also, `string#replace` these special characters with `''` and then join the string without special character with matched character.

```js
var matched = 'a!g?s.bay'.match(/[\!\?\.]/g);
var str = 'ags.bay'.replace(/[\!\?\.]/g, '');
console.log(str+matched.join(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert(string){
   str1 = "", str2 = "";
   for(i=0;i<string.length;++i){
       if(string[i] === '!' ||string[i] === '?' ||string[i] === '.')  
           str1 += string[i];
       else
           str2 += string[i];
   }
return str2+str1;
}
```

I do not understand why are you making it so complicated!